# Android Market payment option for updates

Tags: android, payment, google-play

I basically only need a confirmation that I am not wrong from what I found on the net. Lets assume I have an app on the market for 1 USD in Version 1.0. Now I have a version 2.0

```
a) for 1 USD as well
b) for 2 USD
```

Someone who has bought version 1 already, what option does he have and how much does he have to pay? Am I right that all the future updates to the app are for free?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you increase the price, the users still have access to updates. New users will have to pay the new price.